# Adaptive bit rate support in MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming, adaptive-bitrate

Does iOS MPMoviePlayer or AVPlayer supports "adaptive bit rate" in live streaming ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Put your alternate streams inside a master playlist then set the video source of the player to the URL of this file. The adaptive part is done automatically.